# I have a Filter Icon and cant Seem to Make it Able to Filter Data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filtering

I have a filter icon on my action bar. On click  an alert Dialog like the one below opens up

[image of alert dialog][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kearr.png .
As you can see i want to be able to filter depending on what the user clicks.I have a children elements in firebase for each item in the alertDialog.Example i want when the user clicks on books it only returns the books in the firebase Database

[Image of database][2]
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku0mF.png .

The logic for the filter icon is in my **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.database.fragment.MyPostsFragment;
import com.example.database.fragment.MyTopPostsFragment;
import com.example.database.fragment.PostListFragment;
import com.example.database.fragment.RecentPostsFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList mselected;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private  EditText email;
private  EditText password;
private String EMAIL;
private String PASSWORD;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private MyPostsFragment myPostsFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        private final Fragment[] mFragments = new Fragment[] {
                new RecentPostsFragment(),
                new MyPostsFragment(),
                new MyTopPostsFragment(),
        };

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments[position];
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.length;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.headings)[position];
        }
    };

    ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    findViewById(R.id.fab_new_post).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostSomethingActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


private void FilterIcon(){

    mselected = new ArrayList();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setCustomTitle(LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null))

    .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.Category, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean isChecked) {

            switch (i){

                case  0:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BOOKS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PS3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PS4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PC GAMES",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {





        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });







    AlertDialog dialog =  builder.create();

    dialog.show();
}



private void AccountDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Account Settings");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setItems(R.array.account_setting_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            switch (i){
                case 0:

                    break;
                case 1:

                    DeleteAccount();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();


}





public void DeleteAccount(){



    AlertDialog.Builder  builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.delete_account_layout_credentials,null);

    builder.setTitle("DELETE USER");
    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

             email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.email_address);
             password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.password_place);

            EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim();
            PASSWORD = password.getText().toString().trim();

            RemoveUserFromFirebase();



        }
    }) ;

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
              dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })  ;


    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_chat:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.filter_icon:
            FilterIcon();
            return true;
        case R.id.Account_settings:

            AccountDialog();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



public void showProgressDialog(){

    if(progressDialog==null){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Deleting User");
    } 
    progressDialog.show();



}
public  void hideProgressDialog(){
    if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()){

      progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

public void RemoveUserFromFirebase(){

    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(EMAIL,PASSWORD);
    showProgressDialog();



    user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            user.delete()
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Email or Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            hideProgressDialog();

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                hideProgressDialog();
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,CreateAccount.class));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User Successfully Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    })   ;

        }
    });



}




}
```

I have a class called postListFragments that i use to display the posts

```
package com.example.database.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.example.database.PostDetailActivity;
import com.example.database.R;
import com.example.database.models.Post;
import com.example.database.viewholder.PostViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.MutableData;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;

public abstract class PostListFragment extends Fragment {
    private Fragment currentFragment;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
public PostListFragment() {



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_posts, container, false);
    mRecycler = rootView.findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecycler.setItemViewCacheSize(50);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = getActivity();

    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mActivity, R.style.NewDialog);
    mDialog.addContentView(
            new ProgressBar(mActivity),
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    );
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show();




    setLayout();




    // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
    Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(postsQuery, Post.class)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, int position, final Post model) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

            // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
            if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
            } else {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
            }

            // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View starView) {
                    // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                    DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("posts").child(postRef.getKey());
                    DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabase.child("user-posts").child(model.uid).child(postRef.getKey());

                    // Run two transactions
                    onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                    onStarClicked(userPostRef);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postRef.getKey());
                    startActivity(intent);

                    Log.d("TAG", "onClick: "+ postRef.getKey());
                    Log.d("TAG", "onClick: "+ postRef);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            return new PostViewHolder(getContext(), inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}

private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef) {
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(getUid());
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("postTransaction", "onComplete:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    });
}

public String getUid() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}


public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference);

public void setLayout(){
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager mManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1);
    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

}
}
```